# I made my project and had clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, xcode, macos, clang

I searched all other post saying "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" but i cannot resolve my problem.

After I make I got this message:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [btest] Error 1
```

My Makefile is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O -Wall -m32
LIBS = -lm

all: btest fshow ishow

btest: btest.c bits.c decl.c tests.c btest.h bits.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o btest bits.c btest.c decl.c tests.c

fshow: fshow.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o fshow fshow.c

ishow: ishow.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ishow ishow.c

# Forces a recompile. Used by the driver program.
btestexplicit:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o btest bits.c btest.c decl.c tests.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o btest fshow ishow *~
```

- This is from CS:APP data lab

I have already checked xcode Architecture setting is Standard Architecture(64 bit intel)

Comment: Remove `-m32`, then `make clean` and `make all`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Wow you resolved my problem... Thank you so much. Then Is there any way to make with 32bit ?